# How to run a command involving multiple single and double quotes on windows command line via bsub

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file

I want to run the below command. This command will run on Linux machine (terminal) and will submit a job via bsub on Windows machine (mtbsvr2):

```
"bsub -J shutdownMachines -o //noi/out.txt -e //noi/err.txt -m mtbsvr2 -q win_normal "for /f %i in ( 'bhosts -w pov_test ^| cut -d " " -f1 ^| tail -n +2' ) do shutdown -m \\%i /r /t 02"
```

Content of //noi/err.txt:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

I tried various combinations of single and double quotes, but got no luck in running the command. What can I try next?

Comment: `for` is an internal command within `cmd.exe`.

Comment: What's the purpose of this `for` loop? How is the output different from simply running `bhosts -w pov_test ^| cut -d " " -f1 ^| tail -n +2`? I'm not sure. I would expect it to print the first field of every line, but `cut -d " " -f1` should have done this already. Please clarify this in your question.

Comment: @Bodo, I have added the exact code line. Actually, I want to shutdown all machines containing in machine group (pov_test), and thus using for loop.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `bsub` and `bhosts` commands. I found the syntax `bsub [options] command [arguments]`. Is it necessary to enclose the command in quotes?  Referring to [Compo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76919677/need-help-in-running-a-command-involving-multiple-single-and-double-quotes-on-wi?noredirect=1#comment135600219_76919677): Did you try `cmd.exe /c for /f in ...`? You could also try to use single quotes instead of the outer double quotes and backticks around the command to produce the output to be processed ```'for /f "usebackq" %i in ( `bhosts ...` ) ...'```

Comment: Do I understand the code correct that you run Linux-like commands `cut` and `tail` on a Windows system? If you have `xargs` you could also replace the `for` loop with something like `bhosts -w pov_test ^| cut -d " " -f1 ^| tail -n +2 ^| xargs -I {} shutdown -m \\{} /r /t 02` I'm not sure if the Windows-like quoting of pipe characters is necessary. The placeholder option for `xargs` is an upper-case `i`, not a lower-case `L`. see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html

Comment: @Bodo, xargs thing worked. It helped actually. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote the `xargs` solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be running UNIX-like commands `cut` and `tail` on Windows.

If you also have `xargs` you can replace the Windows `for` loop with piping the command output to `xargs` like

```
bhosts -w pov_test ^| cut -d " " -f1 ^| tail -n +2 ^| xargs -I {} shutdown -m \\{} /r /t 02
```

I'm not sure if the Windows-like quoting of pipe characters is necessary.

In case the font might be ambiguous: The placeholder option for `xargs` is an upper-case `i`, not a lower-case `L`. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html